# Rails 5 Actioncable global message without channels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

How can I send with javascript a global message to all of our subscribed websocket connections without the need of a channel etc. (like the ping message that the actioncable is sending by default globally to all open connections)?

Comment: Hiya - this is two separate questions... can you split them up as two S/O questions?

Comment: Why not use a channel? a channel lets you scale horizontally, which is something you won't be ale to do without a channel (with thanks to your Redis backend)... PINGS are connection mechanisms related to the server's event loop (and yes, you can monkey patch that). They aren't part of the system wide messaging system.

Comment: How could I monkey patch it? I know it is a hack and I won't use it for something mission critical, I just wanted to know how this can be done. I know about the value etc. of the channels and how it can be done with the use of them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot do it directly from JavaScript without channels (it needs to go over Redis first).

I would suggest you do that as a normal post action, and then send the message in Rails.

I would do something like this:

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "/notifications", data: {notification: {message: "Hello world"}}})
```

Controller:

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "notifications_channel",
      message: params[:notification][:message]
    )
  end
end
```

Channel:

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from("notifications_channel", coder: ActiveSupport::JSON) do |data|
      # data => {message: "Hello world"}
      transmit data
    end
  end
end
```

Listen JavaScript:

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create(
  {channel: "NotificationsChannel"},
  {
    received: function(json) {
      console.log("Received notification: " + JSON.stringify(json))
    }
  }
)
```